# C# - How to capture Shift+Del combination event without capturing Shift key only?

Tags: c#, winforms, key, keydown, event-capturing

I have a textbox and a listbox. <kbd>Shift</kbd> must clear the listbox and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> combination must clear the textbox.

This is my code.

```
private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) textBox.Clear();
    if (e.Shift) listBox.Items.Clear();
}
```

It obviously works wrong because the listbox is always cleared when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is down. I need to be able to clear the textbox by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and not clear the listbox at the time.

I have to use only <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> keys and no others.

So what do I have to do?

Comment: Just ignore the shift event for a small time, say 500ms? But it is a bit unclear what you ask. Can't you demo your problem with an [mcve]?

Comment: Which events? How are you monitoring the keyboard? Any code?

Comment: Very unclear what events you are talking about and why you even "capturing" shift alone... Obviously you know that shift state comes with KeyDown events (https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+keydown+shift), so you should be asking about something else - please [edit] post to clarify.

Comment: Please elaborate with some code of how you are capturing. There are usually modifier flags that come with key events that you can check against like Shift, Ctrl, Alt. You normally don't listen explicitly for shift and then listen for another key.

Comment: I've editted my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I started to right an answer, but in reality using Shift as an actual key and also as a modifier for other keys is just a really bad idea. I would just advise you to use anything other than Shift, Ctrl, or Alt to clear your listbox items. Have you ever seen those keys used for functions like you are doing? There's a reason you probably have not ;)

Comment: @TyCobb Actually I have no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me preface this by saying that I would normally advise against using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key alone to trigger an action in any desktop software other than perhaps a game.  Doing so violates the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment): since <kbd>Shift</kbd> is used routinely in the course of normal typing to modify the meaning of other keys, the user is conditioned to expect that pressing it will not do *anything* of consequence by itself, and certainly nothing destructive.  So if the user casually presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> and finds that he has just lost his list of items, he may be quite unpleasantly surprised, particularly if it turns out to be difficult or tedious to undo the damage.

However, you said in the comments that you had no choice in the matter, so with that said, here is a possible solution.

In order to be able to tell the difference between <kbd>Shift</kbd> by itself and a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> combination, we need to capture *both* the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events and use the information gleaned from each.

In the `KeyDown` event, we save the value of the `KeyEventArgs.KeyData` to a private field, but don't take any action on it yet.  `KeyData` contains the combined `Keys` flags representing the primary key that was pressed down, along with any modifier keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> that were held down at the same time.  Note that when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed by itself, it is both the primary key *and* a modifier, so the `KeyData` will contain `Keys.ShiftKey` (the key) combined with `Keys.Shift` (the modifier).

```
private Keys LastKeysDown;

private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    LastKeysDown = e.KeyData;
}
```

In the `KeyUp` event, we look at what keys were released relative to what was last pressed.  We are looking for two specific sequences of keys:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> is pressed, then <kbd>Del</kbd> is released while <kbd>Shift</kbd> is still held down.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed with no other key, then released.

If we find what we're looking for, we initiate the appropriate action, otherwise we do nothing.

```
private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Shift + Delete pressed, then Delete released while Shift still held down
    if (LastKeysDown == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Delete) && e.KeyData == LastKeysDown)
        textBox1.Clear();

    // Shift pressed with no other key, then released
    else if (LastKeysDown == (Keys.Shift | Keys.ShiftKey) && e.KeyData == Keys.ShiftKey)
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

    LastKeysDown = Keys.None;
}
```

Notice that, as a last order of business, we clear the private `LastKeysDown` field.  This helps to ensure that if we get two `KeyUp` events in a row, only the first one is paired with the previous `KeyDown`.  But note this is not foolproof: if you hold a key long enough, the computer's key repeat will kick in and generate additional `KeyDown` events.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to rely on `Key_Down` you could use a `BackgroundWorker` (or a Timer will do as well) that waits for a some milliseconds before it clears the list. If another key comes in during that period, you cancel the BackgroundWorker. Your implementation might look like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Shift && 
        e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("cancelling");
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
        textBox.Clear();
    }

    if (e.Shift && 
        e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey && 
        !backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

}

private void  backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = false;
    // wait 2 seconds (that is a bit long, adjust accordingly)
    Thread.Sleep(2000); // HACK, use a proper timer here
    // tell RunWorkerCompleted if we're good to clear
    e.Result = !backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending;
}

// this gets called on the UI thread
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", e.Cancelled, e.Result));
    if ((bool) e.Result)
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

If you can also leverage the KeyUp event the solution becomes much easier:

```
private bool onlyShift = false; // keeps shift state

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // becomes true if this is the shift key pressed
    onlyShift = e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey;

    if (e.Shift && 
        e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        textBox.Clear();
    }               
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // was the shiftkey the last one in keydown AND
    // are we releasing the shiftkey now
    if (onlyShift && e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
    {
         listBox.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

I would personally use the latter solution.

Comment: Thank you for you help.
One more question. What the difference between e.Shift and (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey). Aren't they equal?

Comment: @J.Doe well, yes. I didn't bother to further optimize.